# Parsing a list of values of the form `{value}` with regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have one string like the following (the number of the `{}` is unknown):

```
{test}{test1}{test2}{test3}{test4}
```

Now I like to get the content in `{}` out and put them into array. How can I do this? I tried:

```
preg_match( "/(\{{\S}+\}*/)*")
```

But the result is wrong. Thanks so much for anyone's help.

Comment: Can we assume that the input is always valid?

Comment: Why do you need `\S` ?  Are you trying to filter out whitespace?

Answer (score 5):

```
preg_match_all('/{(.*?)}/', $string, $match);
print_r($match[1]);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
$string = '{test}{test1}{test2}{test3}{test4}';
$parts = explode('}{', substr($string, 1, -1));
```

This solution avoids using regular expressions which are often slower than simple string functions. Also, many programmers want to avoid regular expressions whenever practical due to preference.

Comment: I can't understand why people hate regular expressions so much

Comment: I like regular expressions but I still upvoted this answer :)  It just so happens that this is a good solution that doesn't need them (well, except it doesn't validate the input).

Comment: Performance is seldom a valid reason for avoiding regexes.  As for preferences, I think @kemp's solution is much clearer than this one.

Comment: You are on the same side of the fence as me then Alan Moore. I knew other responders would provide the regular expression solution, so I decided to provide what the non-regexer's would do.

Answer (score 1):

try `preg_match_all('/\{(.+)\}/U', $text)`